# Expand a function of an arbitrary number of arguments if it is linear in each argument

Tags: python, sympy, multiple-arguments

Is there a way to write a replacement rule for a function f with an arbitrary number of arguments that makes it linear in all its arguments?
An example for when f has three arguments:

1. f( x1+x4 , x2 , x3 ) = f(x4,x2,x3) + f(x1,x2,x3)
2. f( x1 , x2+x4 , x3 ) = f(x1,x2,x3) + f(x1,x4,x3)
3. f( x1 , x2 , x3+x4 ) = f(x1,x2,x3) + f(x1,x2,x4)

Using "Wild" works partially:

```
from sympy import *
f=Function('f')
var("x1:5")
a=Wild("a")
b=Wild("b")
A=Wild('A', exclude=[0])
B=Wild('B', exclude=[0])
expr=f(x1,x2+x4,x3);
print("This one works")
print expr , '->' , expr.replace(f(a,Add(A,B),b),f(a,A,b)+f(a,B,b))
# f(x1, x2 + x4, x3) -> f(x1, x2, x3) + f(x1, x4, x3)
print("This one doesn't on the last entry")
expr=f(x1,x2,x3+x4);
print f(x1,x2,x3+x4) , '->' , expr.replace(f(a,Add(A,B),b),f(a,A,b)+f(a,B,b))
# f(x1, x2, x3 + x4) -> f(x1, x2, x3 + x4)
```

I know I could iterate in a variety of ways over the arguments of the function while altering the replacement, but I was hoping the functionality was built into "Wild" or "replace" already. Mathematica, for example, has "wildcards" like "a___,b___,A___,B___" which mean that "a___" could be an empty sequence, or  a single argument, or a sequence of multiple arguments. For example, in Mathematica,

```
expr /. f[a__,A_Plus,b__] :> f[a,A[[1]],b]+f[a,A[[2;;]],b]
```

would correctly simplify both test cases, and for `f`'s with any number of arguments.

Is there something similar, or is this is close as sympy gets?

Alternatively, might this be possible to do with argument unpacking on a recursive definition starting from something like `def f(*args):`?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Wild matching, I would detect which arguments of f are Add and expand those using [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

```
import itertools
term_groups = [term.args if term.func is Add else (term,) for term in expr.args]
expanded = Add(*[expr.func(*args) for args in itertools.product(*term_groups)])
```

For example, if `expr` is `f(x1+x2+x4, x2+x4, x3*x1)`, then `term_groups` is `[(x1, x2, x4), (x2, x4), (x1*x3,)]` where the last argument yields a 1-element tuple since it's not an Add. And `expanded` is

```
f(x1, x2, x1*x3) + f(x1, x4, x1*x3) + f(x2, x2, x1*x3) + f(x2, x4, x1*x3) + f(x4, x2, x1*x3) + f(x4, x4, x1*x3)
```